# Lazy calculated variable

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a Vector struct that has a lazy calculated variable `magnitude`, but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

This is what I have:

```
struct Vector {

    var x: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            magnitudeActual = -1.0
        }
    }
    var y: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            magnitudeActual = -1.0
        }
    }

    var magnitudeActual: Double = 0.0

    var magnitude: Double {
        if magnitudeActual < 0.0 {
            magnitudeActual = sqrt(x * x + y * y) //cannot assign to "magnitudeActual" in self
        }
        return magnitudeActual
    }

    init() {}

    init(_ x: Double, _ y: Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }

}
```

I have tried many ways to get this to work, but nothing seems to work. Also, a `willGet` would be nice, but doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

> **Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods**
>
> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit self property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the method ends.

---

So then, a `struct` cannot modify itself unless the function doing the modification is flagged as `mutating`. This means you need to define a proper `get` function for the property.

```
var magnitude: Double {
mutating get {
    if magnitudeActual < 0.0 {
        NSLog("Recalc") // just to make sure it's caching the result properly.
        magnitudeActual = sqrt(x * x + y * y)
    }
    return magnitudeActual
}
}
```

Now we can do this

```
var v = Vector(3, 4)
v.magnitude // Recalc 5
v.magnitude // 5

v.x = 5
v.y = 12
v.magnitude // Recalc 13
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to put mutating in some places (like in front of var) but never put it in front of the get, especially since it's optional

Comment: Has anyone tried this lately (Beta 6)?  I think I am getting an internal compiler error in Playground, in the line v.magnitude.  The symptom is that it doesn't finish or give an explicit error.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with your code and the mutating getter proposed by Alex and I found out that

```
init(_ x: Double, _ y: Double) {
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
}
```

doesn't seem to call the setter for x and y or at least not the notification `didSet` and `willSet`. There-for `magnitudeActual` will be 0 if constructed like

```
var v = Vector(3,4)
```

and magnitude won't be recalculated and return 0.

But if constructed like

```
var v = Vector()
v.x = 3
v.y = 4
```

the setters are called, magnitudeActual will be -1 and magnitude will be recalculated.

A fix would be to set the default of `magnitudeActual` to -1, as proposed by GoZoner.

I don't know, if this is behavior by design or a bug.

---

The code I used:

```
struct Vector {

    var x: Double = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        println("set x")

        magnitudeActual = -1.0
    }
    }
    var y: Double = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        println("set y")
        magnitudeActual = -1.0
    }
    }

    var magnitudeActual: Double = -1.0

    var magnitude: Double {
    mutating get {
        if magnitudeActual < 0.0 {
            println("Recalc") // just to make sure it's caching the result properly.
            magnitudeActual = sqrt(x * x + y * y)
        }
        return magnitudeActual
    }
    }

    init() {}

    init(_ x: Double, _ y: Double) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I never noticed. Thanks for solving what would inevitably be some head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
var magnitude: Double {
   return sqrt(x * x + y * y)
}
```

If you really want to only calculate it once, use an immediately executed closure with a lazy member instead:

```
lazy var magnitude: Double = {
   return sqrt(x * x + y * y)
}()
```

Because it is lazy, it will not attempt to do the assignment until it is accessed for the first time. Because the assignment is to the result of a closure, the closure will be executed for the assignment, letting that value be calculated on first access.

Here is a simple example of what the behavior is:

```
class MyClass {
    var x :Double = 10
    lazy var magnitude: Double = {
       return self.x
    }()
}

var obj = MyClass()

obj.x = 12
obj.magnitude // 12 (magnitude was calculated right here after x was changed)

obj.x = 14
obj.magnitude // 12 (magnitude did not change)

obj.magnitude = 8
obj.magnitude // 8 (it changed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you are saving very little, very little buy optimizing the computation of `magnitude`.  You could be done and dusted with simply:

```
class Point {
 var x : Double;
 var y : Double;
 var magnitude : Double { return sqrt (x*x + y*y) }
 var angle     : Double { return atan (x, y) }
}
```

but, if you do need to optimize,

```
class Point {
  var x : Double { didSet { updateMagnitude() }}
  var y : Double { didSet { updateMagnitude() }}
  var magnitude : Double

  func updateMagnitude () { self.magnitude = sqrt (x*x + y*y) }

  init () {
    // ...
    updateMagnitude()
  }
}
```

Comment: your optimization will possibly lead to many unneeded recalculations, as it will trigger the update twice for setting a new pair of x and y. also OP wants to only evaluate magnitude if it is really used.

Comment: Anybody worrying about an extra `sort()` is a) needlessly worrying or b) into some highly specialized computational algorithms.  Alas, the OP was asking a general question and, from me, he got code and a caution about premature optimization.